# Kill worker process in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How do you kill all heroku workers?

I have tried:

`heroku scale worker=0`

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the stack.

The slider interface exposed via the website doesn't let you control Cedar stack applications, one of the following should do the trick though:

```
heroku ps:stop worker
```

or

```
heroku ps:workers 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried logging into the web interface and manually changing the number of workers to zero via the up/down slider?

That is, log into heroku, go to your app's `Resources` page, and drag the "Worker Dynos" slider to zero, then save the changes via the "Save and Apply" button on the top-right.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

New way on Cedar apps is `heroku scale worker=0`

Comment: This is mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: Ha. And so it is. I used to have to use `heroku ps:scale worker=0` but it seems it's since reverted to `heroku scale worker=0`? Dunno. It yelled at me last night

Answer (score 2):

The one that worker for me is `heroku scale worker=0`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
heroku workers 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The current way of scaling dynos is:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=0
```